# How to change slider's selection color in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, controls, customization

I have a `slider`. Is there any way to change the blue color of the selection region to another color (e.g. Black)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the default `SystemColors` to change the color of the selection area.

```
    <Slider  Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="287" Value="6" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True"  SelectionEnd="6" >
        <Slider.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}" Color="Silver" />
        </Slider.Resources>
    </Slider>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Overriding system colors won't work with custom templates.

Set the "IsSelectionRangeEnabled" to true, "SelectionStart" to your beginning value and "SelectionEnd" to your end value.  You can bind "SelectionEnd" to "Value" if you want it to be automatic...

```
<Style x:Key="SliderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Border x:Name="borderBackground" Margin="6,0" Height="4" Background="Gray" />
                    <Canvas Margin="0,-4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Canvas>
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Width="10" Height="20" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionStart" Value="{Binding Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionEnd" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't see how this allows setting a custom color.

Comment: To set the custom color, you need to specify a custom Template.  See updated answer (stripped down to focus on color).

Comment: Thanks Nick. I appreciate you going back to edit this - even after 3 years.