# Cant change the color of a slider wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
                <Slider.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF7C58D2" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}" Color="#FF9890A7" />

                </Slider.Resources>
            </Slider>
```

I used this to solve my problem, by overriding the standard color it should change the color of the slider: [How to change slider's selection color in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557965/how-to-change-sliders-selection-color-in-wpf)

but it didnt change the color, nothing happend

Comment: Maybe you're not using the default style, try adding `Style="{x:null}"` to the slider